# How can I block traffic FROM Amazon Technologies Inc. (possible DDOS attack)

Tags: web-hosting, ddos, ip-blocking

I've a small website (portfolio) and I usually notice traffic of about 10-20MB per day.

But for few recent days I've noticed about 10-15GB (**1000 times more**) each day for 4 days now (and it continue to keep that level).

Most of traffic comes from IPs that, when checked with who-is, are from "Amazon Technologies Inc.", e.g.:

```
ec2-54-174-19-184.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

What would be the **fast** and what would be the **good** solution?

How can I block whole traffic form IPs labeled with "Amazon Technologies Inc."? Or whole traffic from USA and Taiwan (IPs from this two countries appeared when the traffic raised enormously and I don't really mind to block it - I don't really serve any content in English at that website)?

I'm not the hosting provider, I use some local provider in my country.

I have not made any promoting campaigns / SEO optimizations recently.

p.s. **I don't use any Amazon services.**

Comment: As an end user, it will be impossible for us to come up with either a fast or a good solution that you can actually implement. Consider spending the 5€ or so on a VPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon now make available a complete list of their IP address blocks in JSON format here: https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json.

You can use that to create rules to block all of those addresses. How you do that will depend on exactly how your website is set up, but it would be a lot easier if you had your own server or virtual server that you could administer yourself.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Own server is not an option for me now because of costs. Can I block those IPs efficiently with htaccess? Or maybe even when blocked, they will still generate traffic (smaller but x1000 would still be enough to block my website :/ )?

Comment: In my opinion if you want to prevent the traffic to slow down or hang your website, you must act at the IP level, dropping the incoming packets before a TCP connection is actually opened. But of course you could do that only if you have your own (bare metal or virtual) server.

Comment: Are you sure you can't afford a virtual server? You can get them for very few US dollars per month, and you get much greater flexibility to deal with this kind of situation.

Comment: I know this is a few years too late, but for anyone with this problem running a small server on Windows this might help: https://github.com/rkagerer/BlockAmazon